# model builder expressions code block and definitions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, python-parser, expression, terminology

I am having difficulty wrapping my brain around the point of the expression vs the code block. What am I suppose to be defining? I copied the example from calculate value in the ArcGIS help website almost verbatim and yet it says my definition is wrong. More specifically it says a syntax error in line 1.

[image: simple if else statement]

Comment: In a python code block it should be fn(!Z_score!,!Z_top!), it looks like they're defined as a variable in your model, but those variables are out of scope for the code block, there shouldn't be any percents or exclamation marks in the code block. Please ensure you're using the **python** or **python 9.3** parser and not VB (not seen on screen shot). I think it would be better to not populate the Data Type as it's optional; boolean certainly isn't correct.

Comment: Additionally, the variables in the code block don't need to be the same as the real-world variables. You could just call them Zscore and Ztop. Only the variables in the actual expression need to point to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code block you are defining a function, in your expression you are calling that function.  Your function needs to specify new variable names that are used within the function, and you pass the field names to those variables.  The function variables should have new unique names, not the same values you are passing in your expression.

Code Block:

```
def fn(zs, zt):
    if zs => 0:
        return zs
    else:
        return zt
```

Expression:

```
fn(!Z_score!, !Z_top!)
```

So here you are passing the value from `!Z_score!` to your function into a variable called `zs`, and the value from `!Z_top!` into `zt`.  Those values are then used in the function.

And as [commented by Michael Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256852/model-builder-expressions-code-block-and-definitions#comment405580_256852), leave the Data Type as blank as `Boolean` is unlikely to be the correct value.